# Passing touch event (move/swipe) to parent (UITableViewCell), but keeping click event on current view (UITextField)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a form created using UITableView. Each cell is having textfield as child with `textfield.frame = cell.bounds`. With this layout everything works fine except scrolling of form (table). If I move touch on the form slowly it does not scroll form. I understand that textview does not let touch pass through it but is there any way to pass move/swipe touch events to cell but not the click event?

Answer (score -2):

You can always set `textField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`, and it will not respond to any touches.

To detect when the user taps to start editing, you can just listen in the tableView delegate's `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, and then call `[textField becomeFirstResponder]`. This should achieve what you want since the textField frame fills the cell frame anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This was just a case, I have button and textfield both on few cells. This would not work for that case. :(